# Image not positioning dynamically according to the browser size

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Image or any element is not positioning itself when mobile browser is put on landscape mode:

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
</head>
<style>
body{
background: url("bimg.jpg");
margin:0;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="image.png" style="position:relative;top:300px; left:550px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshots of my browser:

**Normal Mode:**

[image: Normal mode]

**Landscape Mode:**
[image: Landscape mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Florin Pop says is true. Additionally, if you want to center an element horizontally and do not know the width of it, you can use one of the following snippets:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">123</div>
</div>
```

or for newer browsers:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">123</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is positioning exactly where you tell it: 300px from top and 550px from the left side of the screen. If you want to position it to the center use:

```
<img src="image.png" style="position:relative;top:300px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

or if you know the image width, let's say for example: 100px, you can center align it with:

```
<img src="image.png" style="position:relative;top:300px; left:50%; margin-left: -50px;">
```

Margin-left -50px is half of the image width (100px).